# How to format time in yaml in symfony

Tags: symfony-1.4, yaml, php

I'm using symfony 1.4 doctrine. I have an output in my database/browser that looks something like this:

> Start time:  12:00:00 End time:    05:00:00

Now I want to change this format like this:

> Start time: 12:00 pm End time: 5:00 pm

I tried to convert this in yaml in the backend application like this:

```
apps/backend/modules/reservation/config/generator.yaml

//some yaml code
fields:
  startime: { date_format: h:i A }
  endtime:  { date_format: h:i A }
```

I use this format but it did'nt work, probably I set in the schema.yml their data types in "time" format:

```
reservation/config/doctrine/schema.yml

//some yaml code
   columns:
     startime: { type: time, notnull: true }
     endtime:  { type: time, notnull: true }
```

I set my startime and endtime to time format just to get the time value only for my project. I did'nt set it to date type because it will affect my front end application. For example if I input `5:00` the display will be `12:00 am`, its because I use date type.

To turn this 5:00:00 to 5:00 pm/am in display, I set it into time data type and I use this syntax like this which I used in showSuccess and Indexsuccess template.

```
<?php echo date('g:i A', strtotime($reservation_application->getStartime()));
```

this code will format 00:00:00 into 12:00 am or something. but it doesnt change (00:00:00) in the data base. ONLY in display.

Is there a way to format this 00:00:00 into 12 hr format in the yaml file? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you save a time, it's always stored without any culture information. (And as soon as you're going to create a multilingual website, you'll be glad of that!).

That said, it's best to use the [DateHelper](http://www.symfony-project.org/api/1_4/DateHelper) when formatting dates in the view. This has a `format_date` function. When you're using this function, don't forget to set the `default_culture` in the `settings.yml` (or set the correct culture in the `sfUser`).

For example `format_date($date, 't');` prints the current time, in the users culture.

For an overview of which patterns you can use, see [this page](http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/formatDateHowTo).